# How can I use Excel to search for one of many text strings, and if present, list all cases in the adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A, I have a sentence. I would like to search these cells for any strings that are within my *StringTriggers* range. If any applicable string is in the sentence, I would like it to populate column B. It is possible for a sentence to contain multiple triggers, in which case, I would like both triggers to be provided in Column B.

The closest I've found is using a combination of ISNUMBER() and SEARCH(), idea coming from [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things). However, other than returning, TRUE or FALSE, I'd like to return the actual trigger(s).

All suggestions welcomed.

Comment: [tag:textjoin] with If and finish with CSE.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: It's worth noting that `TEXTJOIN` is Office365 exclusive, so earlier versions will either require a UDF to combine an array of strings, or a lot of working columns and `INDEX` with `CONCATENATE` to pull it into 1 cell.  But, as @Jeeped said, go with an Array Formula ("CSE") using `IF`, `IFERROR` and `FIND` build the list of matched words.

Comment: @Chronocidal - There are only 30 questions holding the [tag:textjoin] tag. This question is answered in several of them; in at least a couple more are code for a udf textjoin.